# Delphi цикл while eof

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var god:string;
begin
  god:=copy(formatdatetime('yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date)),3,4);
  if opendialog1.Execute then
  if opendialog1.Filename <> null then
  begin
    TextReader1.FileName := opendialog1.FileName;
    try
      ImportFromText.Execute;
      FDQuery1.Close;
      FDQuery1.Open;
    Except
      On E : Exception Do
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;

    FDTable1.Open;
    FDTable1.Edit;
    FDTable1.FieldByName('god').AsString:=god;
    FDTable1.Post;
    FDTable1.Refresh;
    FDTable1.Close;
    while not eof(god) do begin

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Выдает ошибку

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(70): E2008 Incompatible types
>   [dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'

Куда ставить eof помогите исправить

Comment: Что вы своим циклом хотите сделать?

Comment: Вы в функцию проверка конца файла передаете строку, а она принимать должна на вход переменную типа файл.

Comment: Можете исправить в тескте?

Answer (score 0):

вот пример работы с [классическими] текстовыми файлами:

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Eof

в начале `var myFile : TextFile;`

и цикл чтения

```
 while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, text);
    ShowMessage(text);
  end;
```

Comment: при условии того, что в коде в вопросе файлов вообще никаких нет, то данный ответ имеет примерно столько же смысла и пользы, как и вопрос.

Comment: "ответ имеет примерно столько же смысла" - более подробно по ссылке в начале ответа. Нужно ещё подробнее - читаем учебники Паскаля. :-)

Comment: я о том, что автор взял eof  с потолка вообще, а вы ответ пишите, хотя файлы тут не при делах вообще. все рано что задают вопрос про алгебру, а потом в конце раз и так "как размножаются пингвины", и вы рады написать про пингвинов. с чего они тут, раз вопрос математику был, не ясно.